# Implement Semantic Zoom without listview, Gridview?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I am trying to implement Semantic Zoom control but not with listview, Gridview or grouping. My UI has following XAML

**ZoomIn**

```
<!--Your ZoomIn view here-->
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="Item1" />
                        <Grid x:Name="Item2" />
                        <Grid x:Name="Item3" />
                        <Grid x:Name="Item4" />
                        <Grid x:Name="Item5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

**ZoomOut**

```
         <!--Your ZoomOut view here-->
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="ImageItem1" />
                    <Image x:Name="ImageItem2" />
                    <Image x:Name="ImageItem3" />
                    <Image x:Name="ImageItem4" />
                    <Image x:Name="ImageItem5" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

On clicking on an image in Zoomout it should take to the corresponding to Grid in Zoomin view.

How can i achieve this? Till now I have implemented Semantic zoom using listview, gridview and grouping.

Comment: Look this sample 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/18/semantic-zoom-only-supports-gridview-and-listview.aspx

Comment: Yes I have looked into that example but I am not able to get that how will i scroll to that element when I click on that image in ZoomOut.

Comment: Well, you'll have to find the Image's VerticalOffset. You can do this with some math and by doing a TransformToVisual between your ScrollViewer and the respective Item. Then you set the VerticalOffset to the proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sloppy to use a control like `SemanticZoom` for controls it is not intended to use.

Having said that, you can do this:

```
<SemanticZoom>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>One</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Two</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Three</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </GridView.Header>
        </GridView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Four</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Five</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Six</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </GridView.Header>
        </GridView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

Best of luck!